# Will 0.16 amp rated fan replace a 0.3 amp fan?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, fan, watts

I have a noisy PSU fan (400 watt Coolermaster PSU), It's 120mm and 12 volts. I have found an identical fan which is also 12v, but rated 0.16A, as opposed to the original 0.30A fan.

I'm aware PSU maintenance is dangerous, and have waited for the capacitors to discharge. The work is trivial, but I am cautious.
Now I notice the different specs and thought I might get an opinion here before I proceed.

The new one (top) is new, and even branded Coolermaster (found it in a bargain bin for $2).

Edit:

OK. Fan is installed and working. I'll keep an eye on it. But I think it's a win. Thanks for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like many things, fans have an efficiency rating - how much air they'll move per unit of power input, e.g. "5m^3/minute per 10 Watts input"; and are offered across a wide spectrum of quality ranges.

To work things out "properly", you need to know what flow rate the old fan was capable of, what the new one is capable of, and also consider whether or not the PSU is capable of variable speed, and whether your particular environment (e.g. range of typical ambient temperatures) was likely to be operating the fan near the extreme of its capability or not, to then decide if the replacement fan is worthy.

In reality, just put it in and see how it goes :).

Comment: It's for a re-purposed PC set up as a file server. The fan usually went quiet after a few minutes. I'm assuming it's because it was turned off because it wasn't needed. But it sounded like a lawnmower until then.

I guess I just wanted to know if I was doing anything really dangerous with the spec of the fan. But if I'm right you are saying. No, not as far as the fan goes, but there is a small chance it might not keep my PSU cool enough?

Comment: exactly, so long as the voltage matches, and the new one doesn't draw too much more than the original (yours is nearly half, so that's not an issue) then you should be fine, just pay attention to the 'sound' it makes to mentally gauge what speed it's running at, to see if it's likely to keep up a required air flow. (n.b. maximum required air flow will only happen when the system is under heavy CPU/GPU/HDD/etc load).

Answer (score 12):

The replacement fan is rated 44 CFM vs. 70CFM for the original- meaning it moves somewhat more than half  the air (not surprisingly since it uses somewhat more than half the current).

If you're not operating close to the design limit of the power supply you may get away with it, but it will likely shorten the (remaining) life of the power supply.

On the plus side, it's rated < 20dBA vs. 33dBA for the original, so it's supposed to be quiet.

Comment: OK thanks. Where did you get 70CFM from? or 44CFM for that matter?

Comment: I stuck the part numbers (which can be seen on the photos) into google to find the specifications to compare. How else can a quantitative comparison be made?